# How to format pie chart values in Dundas DashBoard 2.5

Tags: dundas

I am using Dundas Dashboard and I am using pie chart. How do I format values that are being displayed in a pie chart. For example if I have a number 120000, I want it formatted as 120,000.

Any ideas and suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Dashboard Designer, select the pie chart and open up the Series property on the property grid.

In the popup window, you will see the properties for the data series shown on the pie chart.  There's a property called "Label Text", and you can set it to a keyword which includes format string specifiers in curly braces.

For example: `#YVALUE1{#,0}` should give you the format you're looking for.

You can get more information how how to use and format keywords here: http://support.dundas.com/Dashboard25.Design_Keywords.ashx

BTW, you should try v3.0 of Dundas Dashboard - there are numerous improvements which make designing dashboards significantly easier.

Answer (score 1):

There is also more information available here:

http://support.dundas.com/Dashboard25.Chart_Usage.ashx

About using the Chart in Dundas Dashboard and labelling.